# Filter lines that contain a fixed number of pattern occurrences

Tags: text-processing, grep

Suppose there is file

```
foo bar cat dog
foo foo cat bar
bar foo foo foo
```

How do we grep for lines with a certain number of occurrences of `foo` e.g. if the number is *1* only the first line in the sample file should be printed ?

Comment: exactly 2 matches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ grep 'foo' file | grep -v 'foo.*foo'
```

First pick out all lines containing `foo`, then remove all lines with `foo` followed by another `foo` somewhere on the line.

If all lines contain at least one `foo` (as in your example), you may skip the first `grep`.

For a general solution to "How do I `grep` for exactly *N* occurrences of a string?":  `grep` for lines with at least *N* matches, then remove lines with *N+1* matches (or more).

Comment: How does one print out all lines with three occurrences of `foo` with this method?

Comment: @Alexander Grep for all lines containing at least three occurrences, then filter out the ones that contain four or more. In the general case: grep for at least *N* occurrences and remove *N+1* occurrences or more.

Answer (score 4):

For the general case - print only lines with exactly *N* occurrences you could use `awk`'s `gsub()` which returns the no. of substitutions made and print the line if that no. matches the requirement e.g. to print lines with exactly three occurrences:

```
 awk '{l=$0;t=gsub(/foo/,"",l)}t==3' infile
```

Another way with `sed`:

```
sed 's/foo/&/3   
t x
: k
d
: x
s/foo/&/4
t k' infile
```

This attempts to replace the 3rd occurrence with itself, if it fails the line is `d`eleted; if successful it branches to `: x` where attempts to replace the 4th occurrence with itself - if successful (it means there are more than 3 occurrences) it branches to `: k` (so that line is also deleted) else it does nothing (besides auto-printing the line...)

---

For the particular case in your example (lines with only one occurrence) you could also use

```
sed '/foo/!d;/foo.*foo/d' infile
```

or something like:

```
pcregrep '^(?:(?!foo).)*foo((?:(?!foo).)*)$' infile
```

Comment: Or just `awk 'gsub(/foo/, "&") == 3'`

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep -c` to count:

```
while read line; do [[ $(echo $line | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep -c foo) == 2 ]] && echo "$line"; done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be to use `perl`, for example by pushing the matches into a list context and then testing it in a scalar context:

```
perl -ne 'my $count = () = $_ =~ /foo/g; print if $count == 1' file
```

or without the explicit scalar variable

```
perl -ne 'print if ( () = $_ =~ /foo/g ) == 1' file
```

This way is easily generalized to return lines with any other desired number of matches.

See for example [Is there a Perl shortcut to count the number of matches in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849329/is-there-a-perl-shortcut-to-count-the-number-of-matches-in-a-string)